# How do I make a link open in an option

Tags: jquery-select2

I added a link to the options, but when clicked only the option is selected. How do I make the link open without making a selection?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-select-multi').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select an option',
    templateResult: formatOption
  });

  function formatOption(option) {
    var $option_text = '';
    var $option_details = '';
    var $option_url = '';

    $option_head = $(
      '<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-between;">'
    );

    $option_text = $(
      '<div style="font-size: 14px; min-width: 70%; height: 100%;">' + option.text + '</div>'
    );

    if ($(option.element).data('details')) {
      $option_details = $(
        '<div style="font-size: 10px; min-width: 70%; height: 100%;">' + $(option.element).data('details') + '</div>'
      );
    }

    if ($(option.element).data('url')) {
      $option_url = $(
        '<div style="font-size: 9px; height: 100%; width: 30%;"><a href="' + $(option.element).data('url') + '">Preview</a></div>'
      );
    }

    $option_foot = $(
      '</div>'
    );

    return $option_head.append($option_text).append($option_details).append($option_url).append($option_foot);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="main">
  <select class="js-select-multi" name="demos[]" id="userInput" style="width: 650px;" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Opt Group 1">
      <option value="90d1aba6" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo.com">Option #1</option>
      <option value="238e894f" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo.com">Option #2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Opt Group 2">
      <option value="574b18e9" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo.com">Option #3</option>
      <option value="5b626e8b" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo.com">Option #4</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with version 3.5.4 of select2. Does not work on select2 4.x

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var select2 = $(".js-select-multi").select2({
    formatResult: format,
    allowClear: true
  }).data('select2');

  select2.onSelect = (function(fn) {
    return function(data, options) {
      var target;

      if (options != null) {
        target = $(options.target);
      }

      if (target && target.hasClass('link')) {
        target_url = $(data.element).data('url');
        //alert(target_url);
        var win = window.open(target_url, '_blank');
        if (win) {
          //Browser has allowed it to be opened
          win.focus();
        } else {
          //Browser has blocked it
          alert('Please allow popup to preview demoboards');
        }
      } else {
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
      }
    }
  })(select2.onSelect);

  function format(option) {
    if (!option.id) {
      return option.text; // optgroup
    } else {
      var $option_text = '';
      var $option_details = '';
      var $option_url = '';

      $option_head = $(
        '<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-between;">'
      );

      $option_text = $(
        '<div style="font-size: 14px; min-width: 70%; height: 100%;">' + option.text + '</div>'
      );

      if ($(option.element).data('details')) {
        $option_details = $(
          '<div style="font-size: 10px; min-width: 70%; height: 100%;">' + $(option.element).data('details') + '</div>'
        );
      }

      if ($(option.element).data('url')) {
        $option_url = $(
          '<div style="font-size: 9px; height: 100%; width: 30%;"><a class="link" href="' + $(option.element).data('url') + '">Preview</a></div>'
        );
      }

      $option_foot = $(
        '</div>'
      );

      return $option_head.append($option_text).append($option_details).append($option_url).append($option_foot);
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.js"></script>

  <select class="js-select-multi" name="demos[]" id="userInput" style="width: 650px;" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Opt Group 1">
      <option value="90d1aba6" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo.com">Option #1</option>
      <option value="238e894f" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo.com">Option #2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Opt Group 2">
      <option value="574b18e9" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo.com">Option #3</option>
      <option value="5b626e8b" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo.com">Option #4</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```