# Enable to add anchor link in dropdown option in select2 Version 4.0.x

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I need to add the link tag inside the dropdown options tag,

I've already found the blogs, but it only works with 3.x.x version.

[How do I make a link open in an option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72708615/how-do-i-make-a-link-open-in-an-option/72750537#72750537)

https://forums.select2.org/t/how-do-i-make-a-link-open-in-an-option/1988

I want the same functionality in a higher version. like example 4.0.x

I'm able to show the link inside the options.

here you can see
[image]

Now when we click on the `preview` it should open the link.

Below is the code for references

```js
//Script code
var select2 = $(".js-select-multi").select2({
  templateResult: format,
  allowClear: true
}).data('select2');

function format(option) {
  //console.log(option);
  if (!option.id) {
    return option.text; // optgroup
  } else {
    var $option_text = '';
    var $option_details = '';
    var $option_url = '';

    $option_head = $(
      '<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-between;">'
    );

    $option_text = $(
      '<div style="font-size: 14px; min-width: 70%; height: 100%;">' + option.text + '</div>'
    );

    if ($(option.element).data('details')) {
      $option_details = $(
        '<div style="font-size: 10px; min-width: 70%; height: 100%;">' + $(option.element).data('details') + '</div>'
      );
    }

    if ($(option.element).data('url')) {
      $option_url = $(
        '<div style="font-size: 9px; height: 100%; width: 30%;"><a class="link" href="' + $(option.element).data('url') + '">Preview</a></div>'
      );
    }

    $option_foot = $(
      '</div>'
    );

    return $option_head.append($option_text).append($option_details).append($option_url).append($option_foot);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="section">
  <h1>This is a Select2</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <select class="js-select-multi" name="demos[]" id="userInput" style="width: 650px;">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="90d1aba6" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo.com">Option #1</option>
        <option value="238e894f" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo.com">Option #2</option>
        <option value="574b18e9" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo.com">Option #3</option>
        <option value="5b626e8b" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo.com">Option #4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the [select2:select event](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events) and check which element is clicked with `event.params.originalEvent.originalEvent.toElement` to redirect when it is a link.

```js
//Script code
var select2 = $(".js-select-multi").select2({
  templateResult: format,
  allowClear: true
}).data('select2');

$(".js-select-multi").on('select2:select', function(event) {
  console.log(event.params.originalEvent.originalEvent.toElement);
  var url = $(event.params.originalEvent.originalEvent.toElement).prop('href');
  console.log(url);

  if (url) {
    // window.location.href = url;
    console.log('window.location.href = url;');
  } else {
    console.log('does not redirect');
  }
});

function format(option) {
  //console.log(option);
  if (!option.id) {
    return option.text; // optgroup
  } else {
    var $option_text = '';
    var $option_details = '';
    var $option_url = '';

    $option_head = $(
      '<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-between;">'
    );

    $option_text = $(
      '<div style="font-size: 14px; min-width: 70%; height: 100%;">' + option.text + '</div>'
    );

    if ($(option.element).data('details')) {
      $option_details = $(
        '<div style="font-size: 10px; min-width: 70%; height: 100%;">' + $(option.element).data('details') + '</div>'
      );
    }

    if ($(option.element).data('url')) {
      $option_url = $(
        '<div style="font-size: 9px; height: 100%; width: 30%;"><a class="link" href="' + $(option.element).data('url') + '" style="cursor: crosshair; background-color: #00ff00;">Preview</a></div>'
      );
    }

    $option_foot = $(
      '</div>'
    );

    return $option_head.append($option_text).append($option_details).append($option_url).append($option_foot);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="section">
  <h1>This is a Select2</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <select class="js-select-multi" name="demos[]" id="userInput" style="width: 650px;">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="90d1aba6" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo1.com">Option #1</option>
        <option value="238e894f" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo2.com">Option #2</option>
        <option value="574b18e9" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo3.com">Option #3</option>
        <option value="5b626e8b" data-details="Customer" data-url="https://yahoo4.com">Option #4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```